# call a function when div of ng-show is really shown

Tags: angularjs

This question is a continuation of:

[Call a function when ng-show is triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056037/call-a-function-when-ng-show-is-triggered)

I have a javascript widget which is embedded in a div. If the div has a dimension of 0 pixel or is hidden it throws an exception.

I have a toggle

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-init="isDisplayed = true">
    <div ng-show="isDisplayed" id="kuku"></div>
    <button ng-click="isDisplayed = !isDisplayed">Toggle</button>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $log) {
    $scope.$watch('isDisplayed', function() {
        if ($scope.isDisplayed) {
            <create funky widget>
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that the watch function is called before the div is shown and i have the same problem.

I have to call the function after the div is shown. How can i accomplish this?

Comment: try using `$timeout` so code runs after digest cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope, $timeout){
  $timeout(function () { 
    $scope.$watch('isDisplayed', function() {
      alert($scope.isDisplayed);
      if ($scope.isDisplayed) {
          alert("working")
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yuhenito/1/edit)**